# ReporteRs package: addparagraph remove leading blank when using stylename ='Normal'

Tags: r, ms-word, reporters

I want to import .txt into .docx using package reporters.
I read the txt file line by line.
When using the addparagraph option: the stylename = "Normal",
refering to the normal style defined in my template 
the leading blanks of each lines disappear (they do not exist anymore).
When i remove the stylename option, the default style imports correctly the leading blanks.
I am not aware of any format/style option in word that would actually prevent this deletion. Hence i understand that the addparagraph, when applying the style remove leading blanks.
Any idea? Thanks in advance

```
# Create a word document to contain R outputs
doc = docx(template = "your_landscape_doc.docx" )
doc = map_title(doc, stylenames = c("Heading1"))


init_Conn <- file('my_file.txt', 'r+') 
Lines <- readLines(init_Conn)
close(init_Conn) 
my_title='just a title'
doc <- addTitle(doc, my_title, level=1)
doc <- addParagraph(doc, Lines, stylename = "Normal")
doc <- addPageBreak( doc )
# Write the Word document to a file 
writeDoc(doc, file = "r-reporters-simple-word-document.docx")
```

[Blanks removed in word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIkk8.png)
[Blanks in initial txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sozf2.png)